# Disable Parent ContextMenu in Chrome Extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, contextmenu

If I have a [Chrome Extension context menu](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/contextMenus) with a submenu, how can I disable the parent so the submenu items are not accessible until the parent is enabled?

```
chrome.contextMenus.create({
  id: "parentMenu",
  title: "Parent Menu",
  contexts: ["browser_action"],
  enabled: false
});

// Create a submenu with two radio buttons

chrome.contextMenus.create({
  parentId: "parentMenu",
  title: "Submenu1",
  contexts: ["browser_action"],
  type: "radio",
  checked: true,
  onclick: function (evt) {}
});

chrome.contextMenus.create({
  parentId: "parentMenu",
  title: "Submenu2",
  contexts: ["browser_action"],
  type: "radio",
  onclick: function (evt) {}
});
```

Even though the parentMenu is marked disabled, it is not disabling.  When I disable the submenus, those do disable as expected.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing it's impossible with a submenu.

A workaround solution would be to remove all submenu items, making the root menu item a normal entry, and disabling it. You lose the arrow, but achieve the disabled state.

Consider some other UI approach though; this seems somewhat clunky.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I had hoped I had overlooked a solution other than rebuilding the menu.  You are right about it being clunky.  Your comment prompted me to augment with an alternate UI.